# Simple regex replace brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Is there an easy way to make this string:

```
(53.5595313, 10.009969899999987)
```

to this String

```
[53.5595313, 10.009969899999987]
```

with JavaScript or jQuery?

I tried with multiple replace which seems not so elegant to me

```
 str = str.replace("(","[").replace(")","]")
```

Comment: There is. I wouldn't restrict myself to one regex, though. One for the left bracket, one for the right bracket.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, since you asked for regex:

```
var input = "(53.5595313, 10.009969899999987)";
var output = input.replace(/^\((.+)\)$/,"[$1]");

// OR to replace all parens, not just one at start and end:
var output = input.replace(/\(/g,"[").replace(/\)/g,"]");
```

...but that's kind of complicated. You could just use [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
var output = "[" + input.slice(1,-1) + "]";
```

Comment: `.replace()` will search and replace throughout the whole string, whereas the given second solution with `.slice()` will only work on the first and last characters of the string.

Comment: @JoeMcLean - `.replace()` only replaces throughout the whole string if you tell it to. But in any case I thought I made it reasonably clear that I only included regex in my answer because the question asked for it,, before then moving on to `.slice()`. OP only wants to replace the first and last characters.

Comment: So why can't we just use replace for something that seems like it should be fairly simple, and it not be extremely complicated for no reason?

Answer (score 18):

For what it's worth, to replace both ( and ) use:

```
str = "(boob)";
str = str.replace(/[\(\)]/g, ""); // yields "boob"
```

regex character meanings:

```
[  = start a group of characters to look for
\( = escape the opening parenthesis
\) = escape the closing parenthesis
]  = close the group
g  = global (replace all that are found)
```

**Edit**

Actually, the two escape characters are redundant and eslint will warn you with:

**Unnecessary escape character: )  no-useless-escape**

The correct form is:

```
str.replace(/[()]/g, "")
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var s ="(53.5595313, 10.009969899999987)";
s.replace(/\((.*)\)/, "[$1]")
```

Answer (score 4):

This Javascript should do the job as well as the answer by 'nnnnnn' above

`stringObject = stringObject.replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']')`

Comment: +1. Note, though, that `replace` only does one replacement when passed a string.

Comment: I assumed as the proposed question he has only one occurrence, the second answer by 'nnnnnn' will also work on this concept when the brackets only occurs once.

Answer (score 3):

If you need not only one bracket pair but several bracket replacements, you can use this regex:

```
var input = "(53.5, 10.009) more stuff then (12) then (abc, 234)";
var output = input.replace(/\((.+?)\)/g, "[$1]");
console.log(output);
```

> [53.5, 10.009] more stuff then [12] then [abc, 234]

Comment: THIS is the elegant answer one is looking for.